# MySQL Update during CSV import question

Tags: mysql, syntax, import

Okay, so I have this CSV file of products and all the products have an ID number.  I am going to import this CSV into an existing (empty) database table where the columns in the database are named the exact same name as the first-row columns in the CSV file.

There is one extra column in the DB called URI.  I need to build this during (or after is okay too) the import of the CSV file, based on info in the CSV file.

For example, I know the URI is going to start with-

http://foo.com/prodinfo.asp?number=

I need to append to basically build the URI and insert into that last field so that the URI looks like-

`"http://foo.com/prodinfo.asp?number=" . $item_number . "&id=123456"`

The first string and the last string will be the same every iteration, only the item_number will changed based on that column in the DB.

Now the question.  I can easily write a PHP script to do the update for me, however, I don't know enough about MySQL to know whether it can be done during the import of the CSV or if there's some easy MySQL syntax I can run in SQLyog or something to do it without having to write/run a script each time?

Okay, I think that explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `table`, the item_number column is called `number`, and that the URI column is called `URI`, you can issue the following SQL statement right after you are done importing the CSV:

```
UPDATE table SET URI=CONCAT('http://foo.com/prodinfo.asp?number=',number,'&id=123456');
COMMIT;
```

If you don't want to do this manually after each import, you can have MySQL run the statement automatically [as part of a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html).

Comment: Actually I just ran this and it filled my uri column with zeroes.  Thoughts?

Comment: yes; you probably defined your URI column type to be some sort of numeric type instead of `varchar` :)

Comment: No, it was set to varchar(255) (double-checked just now).

Building off of your suggestion, I was able to get it to work like this:

UPDATE table SET URI=CONCAT('http://www.foo.com/prodinfo.asp?number=', number, '&id=123456')

Comment: My bad, updated the answer to use CONCAT (`||` concatenates strings under Oracle, Postgres etc.)